# PHP ООП не видит класс

Tags: php, ооп

У класса `candidateService` объявлено пространство имен `namespace app\services;`
Импортирую его в другом классе `use app\services\candidateService as candidateService;`, но PHP его не видит:

> Fatal error: Class 'app\models\candidateService' not found in Z:\home\test.ru\www\index.php on line 8

В чем может быть проблема?

**index.php**

```
use app\services\candidateService as candidateService;

$candidateService = new candidateService();
$candidate = $candidateService->getCandidate(1);
print_r($candidate);
```

**candidateService.php**

```
namespace app\services;


use app\managers\dbManager as Database;

class candidateService
{
    private $Surname, $Name, $Patronymic, $Mail, $LastContact, $Status, $Vacancies, $Database = null;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->Database = new Database();
    }

    public function getCandidate($id)
    {
        return $this->Database->Query("SELECT * FROM `candidates` WHERE `id`='$id';");
    }
}
```

Comment: Во-первых, для use достаточно `use app\services\candidateService`, если вы не хотите использовать алиас для этого класса. Во-вторых, как вы инклюдите сам класс?

Comment: импорт нейспейса не значит require файла с этим классом.

Comment: Пишите собственный загрузчик, который будет правильно подключать файлы классов

Answer (score 1):

У вас отсутствует подключение этого самого класса, отсюда и его недоступность.

```
define('PATH_TO_MODELS',$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/PATH/TO/MODELS/');

include_once PATH_TO_MODELS.'candidateService.php';

use app\services\candidateService;

$candidateService = new candidateService();
$candidate = $candidateService->getCandidate(1);
print_r($candidate);
```

В коде нужно указать путь, где у вас лежат модели. В идеале, для этой цели используется [spl_autoload_register()](https://secure.php.net/manual/ru/function.spl-autoload-register.php)

И для случая, если у вас все модели находятся в папке models корня хоста и имя класса в точности соответствует имени файла с этим классом, код будет выглядеть так.

```
define('MODELS',$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/models/');
spl_autoload_register('autoload');
function autoload($class)
{
    $file = MODELS.$class.'.php';
    if (is_readable($file))
        include_once($file);
}

use app\services\candidateService;

$candidateService = new candidateService();
$candidate = $candidateService->getCandidate(1);
print_r($candidate);
```